# Java permutation of String array

Tags: java, permutation

I am trying to find all possible options of combining a string array with two elements. Let's say, the array has two elements {"we","are"}. The output should be:"we" "are" "we are" "are we"
I could manage, with some search, to put together this code:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] strings = {"we", "are"};

    final int maxbit = 1 << strings.length;

    for (int p = 0; p < maxbit; p++) {
        String finalString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            if ((1 << i & p) > 0) {
                finalString += strings[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(finalString);
    }

}
```

My problem is, that I am missing one solution, the output is following: "we" "are" "we are".
So I am missing the "are we" option, would I need to use recursion to solve this problem or can this code be modified to show the remaining option?

UPDATE: solution found with the help of answers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test = { "are", "we"};
    language(test.length, test, "");
}

private static void language(final int n, final String[] syllables, final String currentWord) { // example of N = 3
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(currentWord);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < syllables.length; i++) {
            if (currentWord.equals(syllables[i])){
                language(n - 1, syllables, "" + syllables[i]);
            }else{
                language(n - 1, syllables, currentWord + syllables[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `{"we"}` and `{are}` are _not_ permutations of `{"we", "are}`. A permutation has always the same size as the source array.

Comment: So I am understanding this wrong, it is not permutation? What would this be called, if this output would be needed?

Comment: I think you are looking for all possible subset.

Comment: One approach would be: 1) Do only the permutation. I.e. permute _all_ array elements together. For a 2-sized array, there are only 2 permutations. 2) Afterwards, you can build up all possible sub-sets of your source array and then permute all of these. That would lead to a generic program, which will need much more loops and/or recursion, I guess.

Comment: Doing that with bit shifts etc. looks a little complex to me, especially for someone with as little experience as you seem to have. I'd probably go for a recursive option that takes one of the remaining elements in the set or none (thus creating the shorter subsets).

Comment: Your permutation code is not right. Take an array of size 3 and see for yourself. Also, what's a `res`?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The res was left there. I have little experience with java, started to study it a few days ago. I will look into a recursive solution.

Comment: I think, I have found a solution, not quite sure I fully understand how recursion works, but will study more into it. Thanks for the answers, helped me a lot. Updating post with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another example

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {"we", "are"};
        
        String str = Arrays.toString(strings);
        
        System.out.println("Java String array to String = "+str.replace(",","").replace("[","").replace("]",""));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use regex for better replace

Answer (score -1):

I looked over it for a while, and found 2 ways to make it based on your code:

this will print out every permutation once, and DOESN'T have to include all the words:

```
public static void recPerm(String... input) {
    recHelper(input, input.length, "");
}

private static void recHelper(String[] input, int length, String currentWord) {
    if (currentWord != "")
        System.out.println(currentWord);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (!currentWord.contains(input[i]))
            recHelper(input, length - 1, currentWord + input[i]);
    }
}
```

this will print out every permutation once, and DOES have to include all the words:

```
public static void maxRecPerm(String... input) {
    maxRecHelper(input, input.length, "");
}

private static void maxRecHelper(String[] input, int length, String currentWord) {
    if (length == 0)
        System.out.println(currentWord);
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (!currentWord.contains(input[i]))
            maxRecHelper(input, length - 1, currentWord + input[i]);
    }
}
```